# C# alternative to runtime optional parameters?

Tags: c#

I'm not sure how to go about doing this, after a bit of research I couldn't really find something that fits my needs. The only thing I could find is from [another coding language entirely](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/3947#discussioncomment-85787). I think I might be over-complicating things but I'm blanking and can't seem to wrap my head around this problem.

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve, say I have a class `Item`:

```
public class Item {
    public int val { get; set; } = 1;
    public void Link(Item i) { ... }
}
```

And in some other class that manages `Items`, I have this method:

```
void LinkPair(int val = GetLowestVal()) {
    var pair = GetItems(val);
    pair[0].Link(pair[1]);
}
```

Basically what I want it to do is: if given a value `val`, find and link a pair of `Items` with matching values, otherwise just link a pair both with the lowest value in the list. Unfortunately `void LinkPair(int val = GetLowestTier())` isn't a valid signature. Also, since `val` is an `int` I can't set its default to `null`, otherwise I would so something like this I presume:

```
void LinkPair(int val = null) {
    val = val ?? GetLowestVal();
    ...
```

I'd like to avoid having to create another overloaded method since I might end up with quite a few variations of these. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The correct syntax is `void LinkPair(int? val=null)`. There's nothing wrong with it. On the other hand, `public int val = 1;` is wrong - fields are implementation details. Use properties for anything that should be accessible by other classes. Only properties are considered part of a class's API

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I didn't think I could use nullables as a method parameter. Also sorry, I simplified it too much it seems, I have edited the question.

Comment: Would you mind posting your comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assign `null` to an `int`. You'll have to use int?

```
void LinkPair(int? val = null) {
    val = val ?? GetLowestVal();
```

If you know that `val` will never be 0 you can use this as the default :

```
void LinkPair(int val = 0) {
    val =  val!=0? val : GetLowestVal();
```

`0` is the default for numbers so this is equivalent to :

```
void LinkPair(int val = default) {
    val =  val!=0 ? val : GetLowestVal();
```